# Improving view performance in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following view:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    IdOpportunity, IsNull(ShortName,'-') as ShortName,  
    OpportunityDesc,IdClientSolic, ClientSolicDesc, IdSocResp, 
    SocRespName, IdGroupAdm,
    GroupAdmDesc, IdOffice, OfficeDesc, 
    IdArea, AreaDesc, OperationType
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [OPER_ID] as IdOpportunity, 
         o.CASETITLE as OpportunityDesc,
         o.CLIENTSOLICID as IdClientSolic, 
         o.CLIENTSOLICNAME as ClientSolicDesc, 
         o.GROUPADMID as IdGroupAdm,
         o.GROUPADMDESC as GroupAdmDesc, o.OFFICEID as IdOffice, 
         o.OFFICEDESCRIPTION as OfficeDesc, 
         o.AREAID as IdArea, o.AREADESC as AreaDesc,
         CASE 
             WHEN LEN(partner_no) = 10 
                THEN (SELECT DISTINCT shortname
                      FROM [SAP].dbo.tb_user_list_prod
                      WHERE empid = right(partner_no, 8)
                        AND year(enddate) = 9999)
             ELSE partner_no
         END as ShortName, 
         o.TYPEOPERATION as OperationType, u.shortname as IdSocResp, 
         u.NAME + ' ' + u.Lastname_1 + ' ' + u.lastname_2 as SocRespName
     FROM 
         [SAP].[dbo].[ZTB_OPPMATT_BP]
     INNER JOIN 
         [SAP].dbo.tb_opportunity_list_prod o ON o.OPPORTUNITYID = [oper_id]
     INNER JOIN 
         [SAP].[dbo].[tb_user_list_prod] u ON u.empid = SUBSTRING(o.[LEADINGID], 3, LEN(o.[LEADINGID]))
     WHERE
         partner_fct IN ('ZCREA','Z6','Z2','ZLEAD','00000014','00000032') 
         AND PROCESS_TYPE IN ('ZOSE','ZOPB','ZOPP')) as WorkGroupView  
WHERE
    ShortName <> '' AND ShortName <> '-'
```

Base tables have the following information:

- ZTB_OPPMATT_BP : 145000 rows
- tb_opportunity_list_prod : 46000 rows
- tb_user_list_prod: 120000 rows

If I try to execute this view in sql server, it takes about 16-20 seconds to finish for 150.000 rows (for now, is going to increase in future).

How can I increase the view performance?

I read about indexed views, but the base tables are not static so it seems dangerous to put an index that has to be updated anytime we create a new user/opportunity/whatever. Besides, I cannot modify the base tables, just read them.

I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to do anything with an indexed view to keep it up to date, that's automatic. Take a look at your actual execution plan and see what's taking the time. Ensure your indexes are up to date. Also, take that subquery out of that CASE expression, add it as a cross join if you need to

Comment: the query is very dependet to index structure in your tables. show us the index defenitions.

Comment: Review each `DISTINCT`. Second is sensless - it has to be TOP 1 or must fail because of multiple rows in result. And substring in join is a bad idea of course.

Comment: That inner join to tb_user_list_prod is problematic for sure. You have nonSARGable predicates in the join. That means an index scan no matter what. The engine has to evaluate each and every row. Could you split that column in to the actual values so you aren't forced to use substring and len?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build your view without subquery:

```
SELECT   [OPER_ID] as IdOpportunity,
         CASE WHEN LEN(partner_no) = 10 THEN u1.shortname ELSE partner_no END as ShortName, 
         o.CASETITLE as OpportunityDesc,
         o.CLIENTSOLICID as IdClientSolic, 
         o.CLIENTSOLICNAME as ClientSolicDesc,
         u.shortname as IdSocResp, 
         u.NAME + ' ' + u.Lastname_1 + ' ' + u.lastname_2 as SocRespName,
         o.GROUPADMID as IdGroupAdm,
         o.GROUPADMDESC as GroupAdmDesc, 
         o.OFFICEID as IdOffice, 
         o.OFFICEDESCRIPTION as OfficeDesc, 
         o.AREAID as IdArea, 
         o.AREADESC as AreaDesc,
         o.TYPEOPERATION as OperationType
FROM [SAP].[dbo].[ZTB_OPPMATT_BP]
INNER JOIN [SAP].dbo.tb_opportunity_list_prod o 
    ON o.OPPORTUNITYID = [oper_id]
INNER JOIN [SAP].[dbo].[tb_user_list_prod] u 
    ON u.empid = SUBSTRING(o.[LEADINGID], 3, LEN(o.[LEADINGID]))
LEFT JOIN [SAP].dbo.tb_user_list_prod u1
    ON u1.empid = right(partner_no, 8) AND year(u1.enddate) = 9999
WHERE partner_fct IN ('ZCREA','Z6','Z2','ZLEAD','00000014','00000032') 
        AND PROCESS_TYPE IN ('ZOSE','ZOPB','ZOPP')
        AND (CASE WHEN LEN(partner_no) = 10 THEN u1.shortname ELSE partner_no END) NOT IN ('','-')
```